# как запустить https node-express-сервер без домена

Tags: node.js, nginx, apache, express, https

У меня есть виртуальная машина, на ней размещен node.js (express) сервер. Домена для сервера у меня нет. Сервер на виртуальной машине, так как используется база данных на mongodb. Иначе, всё решилось бы, за счет использования сайта glitch. А сервера, которые там размещаются не могут использоваться как хранилища базы данных на mongodb.

Сейчас сервер доступен по http. Например: http://51.250.27.86:3002/reg. Если вы перейдете, то увидите небольшое сообщение от сервера.

Я разместил frontend часть, на githabe-page. Если я укажу в качестве backend'а данный адрес сервера (http://51.250.27.86:3002/reg), то получу ошибку из-за http, вместо https.

Какой самый простой способ решить данную проблему.

Что пробовал:

1. Пытался выпустить ssl сертификат. Но не понимаю, как это сделать для ip адреса.
2. Пытался настроить nginx. Но я умею его настраивать только если есть домен. Может кто-нибудь пришлет настройку файла `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` чтобы все работало без домена? И тогда вопрос, в этом случае все равно нужны будут ssl сертификаты?
3. Еще я думал об идее мини сервера на сайте glitch, так как сервера размещенные там будут https. И этот мини сервер (glitch) будет пересылать запросы на большой сервер (виртуальная машина)
4. Создать на виртуальной машине только базу данных mongodb. На glitch разместить сервер, который будет сохранять данные в базу данных mongodb на виртуальной машине. Но я не знаю как такое сделать.

Посоветуйте что-нибудь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сгенерировать самоподписанный сертификат можно командой:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 \
        -keyout /etc/nginx/privkey.pem \
        -out /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem \
        -subj "/C=/ST=/L=/O=/CN=example.com"
```

example.com не нужно ни на что менять.

Фрагмент конфига Nginx для https и без домена:

```
server {
   listen :443 ssl;
   listen :80;

   server_name _;

   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;

   ...
}
```

Comment: Ещё один вариант-использование домена третьего уровня, что то типа mymongo.bespltno.com В сети множество сайтов, которые позволяют зарегистрировать запись типа а в домене третьего уровня бесплатно

Comment: при попытке сделать сертификат я получаю: req: No value provided for Subject Attribute C, skipped
req: No value provided for Subject Attribute ST, skipped
req: No value provided for Subject Attribute L, skipped
req: No value provided for Subject Attribute O, skipped

Comment: Но в этом случае сертификат все равно создался. не используя nginx я получаю опять предупреждение, что сайт небезопасный и что сертификат самоподписанный. Certificate CN
example.com
Issuer CN
example.com
Valid Until
Jun 3 12:36:42 2023 GMT
Self signed certificate

Comment: эти атрибуты необязательные, все верно, это не ошибка

Comment: да, на самоподписанные сертификаты браузеры ругаются, но при этом https можно использовать

Comment: Да, теперь нет нужды использовать порт для получения данных. Но, само собой,  предупреждение (ограничение) о самоподписанном сертификате не исчезло. Остается способ, который написан выше, о домене третьего уровня. А для ай пи адреса точно нет возможности выписать сертификат, на который браузер не будет ругаться?

Comment: можно, но IP должен принадлежать вам https://sectigostore.com/page/ssl-certificate-for-ip-address/

Comment: Я не правильно выразился. То что за деньги можно получить сертификат я знаю. Я не знаю как за бесплатно.

Comment: Получилось решить абсолютно все проблемы данного вопроса с помощью домена третьего уровня. Для этого я воспользовался сайтом https://www.noip.com/. Тут всё просто. Нажал три кнопки. Указал ай пи. Победа.